# Can you use jQuery to display a view?

Tags: views, javascript

I want to do something similar to views slideshow. The thing is my javascript is written already. I would like my javascript to be able to be integrated within the drupal framework from views. The JQuery just is a simple image slideshow like this one [here](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_jquery_background_image_slideshow.html).  I just would prefer that I could show all or specific view field content instead of putting in the url in the javascript the long way. I want these images to come directly from a content type. Can you show me how?

Comment: Being a newbie doesn't justify to write confusing english :) okay i'm not a native speaker, but i still don't get what you actually want.

Comment: @DanielWehner, +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a small module that will be called through ajax:

```
function MYMODULE_node_menu() {
    return array(//$items
        'MYMODULE/%' => array(
            'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_display_view',
            'page arguments' => array(1),
            'access callback' => TRUE,
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        )
    );
}
function MYMODULE_display_view($view_name) {
    // display your view depending on $view_name
   $view = views_get_view($view_name);
   $view->execute();
   echo $view->render();
}
```

Get a views html by making an ajax call using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax('MYMODULE/YOUR_VIEW_NAME', {
           sucess:function(data) {
              // data will contain the html for your view
           }
   });
 });
```

You might find the following [Drupal 7 Advanced Ajax](http://www.slideshare.net/merlinofchaos/drupal-7-advanced-ajax) helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the slides. Didn't know about it. It should be on d.o.